# Hadoop's dfshealth page won't show up

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I installed Hadoop on linux 10.4 64bit in a virtual machine. I set all the configurations and it worked fine. The dfshealth page showed properly. I shut down the vm and now, when I try to open the dfshealth page, firefox flashes the page, like trying to show the information but then throws the error that the connection can't be stablished.

I tried the `start-all.sh` but it wont work. Tried re-running some scripts but it won't work either.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you asked Firefox to request a page from a server that is down?

Comment: When you tried to restart, does it throw any errors? Check the log files

Comment: @VusP When i restarted, everthing started perfectly, stoped it all and restarted again but nothing 
It seem's that hadoop is not able to start correctly the namenode nor the jobtracker, however it doesn't shows an error while starting them.
Check the screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/ItbPyN1.jpg

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi when I start hadoop, there's jsp page that should show up at localhost:50070 indicating that everything is going fine. In this case it doesn't. Check the link above